# What is a stack in assembly and how does the command .stack work?

Tags: assembly, memory, tasm

I'm just gonna jump straight into it: 
I'm learning assembly and am using turbo assembler. I literally just started learning so I'm trying to familiarize myself with some pre-defined services of the language and also am reading up on registers so that I can better understand why what's happening is actually happening. However, I can't seem to wrap my mind around what a stack actually means in this instance.

The way I understand stack is that it follows the procedure of LIFO regarding how instructions and data are treated. So what does the command .stack 100h do?

Am I assigning a limit to amount of things that can be loaded in the stack?

So what does this line actually do?:

```
.stack 100h
```

If it accepts numbers in other bases, is .stack 100h the same as .stack 256d? Will there be any technical or internal difference?

Comment: Yes, it sets the stack size. Yes, it accepts numbers in any base, as per your assembler's syntax.

Comment: Have you tried reading the tasm manual?

Comment: If you mean turbo assembler for 16 bit code, `.stack` is only used to reserve stack space for .exe programs. For a .com program, when it starts, cs=ds=es=ss = program segment prefix, and stack pointer is initialized to 0fffeh.

Comment: @Jester So is .stack 100h the same as .stack 256d? Is there any technical or internal difference?

Comment: @rcgldr : well when a full 64KiB is available _SP_ is set to 0000h and the return address of 0000h is pushed on the stack giving the appearance it started at 0fffeh. Address 0000h is in the PSP and is an int 20h instruction that will terminate the program. COM programs can be less than 64KiB if there is less than that remaining on the system. In those cases _SP_ will be set to an offset below the end of available memory.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I posted an answer to this with some guesswork about how an EXE might have its initial SS:SP set up.  Does `.stack 100h` guarantee that `SP=100h`, or can an EXE program-loader choose to put SP higher and SP correspondingly lower to allow using more stack than initially asked for?

Comment: @PeterCordes : I already upvoted your answer. As for EXE programs the stack is relocated by adding the base segment the EXE is loaded at to the 0 based Stack Segment in the DOS EXE header. SS:SP in the DOS header isn't overridden by the DOS loader, only has a fixup done to it.

Comment: Of course once the program is running, the program itself is free to change the stack address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.stack` sets metadata in a `.exe` that affects how much memory the program-loader allocates for the stack segment.

One way for this to work is that on entry to a program, the `SS` base address is the lowest usable stack address and SP = the size you gave to `.stack`.  If `SP` was higher, you could accidentally use more than `.stack` bytes without having SP wrap around, creating a stack-clash with something else.  (IDK if there's a standard that requires an EXE program-loader to choose a specific offset for SP.)

It doesn't create any extra instructions *inside* your program.  Its argument is just a numeric constant; you can specify it in any number base you like, depending on your assembler.

---

`.stack` also has no effect for `.com` programs: those start with `cs=ds=es=ss` with `SP=0fffeH` (or lower if less than 64kiB of contiguous memory is available).

(In a `.com`, SP points to a return address of `0` (in the PSP), where there's an `int 20h` instruction that will make an exit system call.  So before pushing that 0, SP started at `0000h`)

---

This answer is a summary of comments, thanks to @Jester, @rcgldr and @MichaelPetch for confirming that it is as simple as it looks, and pointing out the difference between .exe can .com programs.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now my only confusion and final clarification I need is this: does the number base used to specify the stack size in .stack 100(h/d/b) affect the memory used or the WAY the memory is used? 

Because now my assumption is that: .stack 100h is equivalent to .stack256d ... right?

Comment: @Eshmam: no, of course it doesn't have any effect.  Just like `mov al, 10h` and `mov al, 16` assemble to identical machine code.  Or C `x = 16` and `x = 0x16` are the same value after parsing the numeric literal.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I assume you meant `x = 16 and x = 0x10` are the same